# azure DevOps API not returning all fields for WorkItems

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm trying to execute a POST request with Azure DevOps on my WorkItems and get all the Others Tags on the WorkItems .
This is my query

> https://dev.azure.com/{orgenezation}/{project}/{Team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1
>   and the Body is

```
{
  "query": "select [System.Id],[System.Description], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = @project and [System.Tags] contains 'Automation' and [System.Tags] contains 'board1'"

}
```

from some reason I do not get the right data and have missing data from the result , like Description,Tags.

```
...
  "workItems": [
        {
            "id": 6441,
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/eb25462e-351c-4364-a55a-e9e6029bffba/_apis/wit/workItems/6441"
        },
        {
            "id": 6442,
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/eb25462e-351c-4364-a55a-e9e6029bffba/_apis/wit/workItems/6442"
        },
...
```

what should I do with this issue?

Comment: Currently ,this is as designed . If Shamrai Aleksander's answer is helpful to you ,you could consider to accept it . Also you could add your request for this issue on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site . Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as designed. It returns only ids and urls. Here you can find the example with request and result: [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Then you can use [Work Items - Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and specify all ids from your wiql result. Additionally, you can specify only needed fields: [Get list of work items for specific fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples).

Comment: this is the worst api ever , way execute 2 query ? I have the query and did the right execution to get all the fields, and you tell me that i can't , so way they gives this query as post api ?

Comment: @shaharnakash I agree with you. We have fields defined in a wiql and want to see them in a result. However, the query with rest api returns list of [WorkItemReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#workitemreference) for a flat query or list of [WorkItemLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#workitemlink) for trees or direct links.

Comment: @shaharnakash You are absolutely right.. I think some trainees in microsoft behind the apis... :)

Comment: So, to be clear: When we send a WIQL query to the API, we should not bother putting anything useful in the `SELECT` clause (i.e. just any field name will do), as that part of the query is ignored?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes. It returns only ids.